# What do werewolves and vampires think of each other in Middle-earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, vampire, werewolf

The TVTropes article [Fur Against Fang](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FurAgainstFang) has this to say about vampires and werewolves in Middle-earth:

> Werewolves despised vampires, considering them “rats with wings” and vampires regarded wolves like big bullies. It is not so evident in *The Silmarillion*, but when you read the *Lay of Beren and Luthien* and the meeting with Carcharoth, the text makes clear that Carcharoth is shocked of seeing a vampire and wolf together and wolves hate vampires.

On TVTropes, “*Lay of Beren and Luthien*” is linked to *The History of Middle-earth*. I assume that it’s talking about *The Lay of Leithian* in *The Lays of Beleriand*, but I can’t find the text “rats with wings” anywhere in that book.

Is there a passage that describes what werewolves and vampires thought of each other? I am looking for either the passage referenced on TVTropes, or anything else that describes what vampires and werewolves think of each other.

Related questions:

- [In the Silmarillion what is meant by Vampires and Werewolves?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/in-the-silmarillion-what-is-meant-by-vampires-and-werewolves)
- [Vampires in Middle Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89891/vampires-in-middle-earth)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The intrepid TVTropes editor<sup>1</sup> is likely referring to this passage from Canto XII, though I would argue they misinterpret it (emphasis mine):

> But what is this that crawls beside,
> slinking as if 'twould neath thee hide?
> Though winged creatures to and fro
> unnumbered pass here, all I know.
> I know not this. Stay, vampire, stay!
> **I like not thy kin nor thee**. Come, say
> what sneaking errand thee doth bring,
> **thou winged vermin**, to the king!
> Small matter, I doubt not, if thou stay
> or enter, or if in my play
> I crush thee like a fly on wall,
> or bite thy wings and let thee crawl.'
>
> <sup>*The History of Middle-earth* III *The Lays of Beleriand* Chapter 3: "The Lay of Leithian" Canto XII</sup>

While the TVTropes editor interprets this passage as saying that *all* werewolves dislike vampires, I don't know that I would be so confident; in my estimation, it only means that *Carcharoth* doesn't like vampires.

---

<sup>1</sup> And note that it really *is* just one person's opinion; TVTropes is notoriously [uncurated](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Administrivia/ThereIsNoSuchThingAsNotability)

Comment: Nice little jab at the flying rodent though. Do vampires carry rabies?

Comment: Do you know of any other passages that might shed light on the general feeling of werewolves about vampires? I'm not sure that vampires are even mentioned outside of _The Lays of Beleriand_ and _The Silmarillion_, so I'm guessing that the passage you quoted is the closest I'm going to get.

Comment: @amaretto I don't, although I haven't combed through the prose versions of the story in exhaustive detail. I'm reasonably confident these are the only writings where vampires are mentioned, but when I have more time I can do a more thorough search

Comment: OK, I'll accept this answer then. Where did you get prose versions of the stories? I searched through _The Lays of Beleriand_ on Amazon but found the poetry difficult to parse.

Comment: @amaretto Scattered throughout *History of Middle-earth*. Because that series shows how the narrative progressed over time, there's no single place to find them all